# locale-dependent ordering for std::string

Tags: c++, string, locale

I am trying to compare `std::string`s in a locale-dependent manner.

For ordinary C-style strings, I've found `strcoll`, which does exactly what I want, after doing `std::setlocale`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <cstring>

bool cmp(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    return strcoll(a, b) < 0;
}

int main()
{
    const char* s1 = "z", *s2 = "å", *s3 = "ä", *s4 = "ö";

    std::cout << (cmp(s1,s2) && cmp(s2,s3) && cmp(s3,s4)) << "\n"; //Outputs 0
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8");
    std::cout << (cmp(s1,s2) && cmp(s2,s3) && cmp(s3,s4)) << "\n"; //Outputs 1, like it should

    return 0;
}
```

However, I'd like to have this behaviour for `std::string` as well. I could just overload `operator<` to do something like

```
bool operator<(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    return strcoll(a.c_str(), b.c_str());
}
```

but then I'd have to worry about code using `std::less` and `std::string::compare`, so it doesn't feel right.

Is there a way to make this kind of collation work for strings in a seamless manner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

operator() of std::locale is just what you are searching.  To get the current global locale, just use the default constructor.

Comment: That's handy. It makes the standard collections work without effort.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ library provides the [collate facet](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/collate/compare/) to do locale-specific collation.

Comment: operator() on locale is the easiest way I know to access it.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching around I realized that one way to do it could be to overload the `std::basic_string` template to make a new, localized string class.

There is probably a gazillion bugs in this, but as a proof of concept:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

struct localed_traits: public std::char_traits<wchar_t>
{
    static bool lt(wchar_t a, wchar_t b)
    {
        const std::collate<wchar_t>& coll =
            std::use_facet< std::collate<wchar_t> >(std::locale());
        return coll.compare(&a, &a+1, &b, &b+1) < 0;
    }

    static int compare(const wchar_t* a, const wchar_t* b, size_t n)
    {
        const std::collate<wchar_t>& coll =
            std::use_facet< std::collate<wchar_t> >(std::locale());
        return coll.compare(a, a+n, b, b+n);
    }
};

typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t, localed_traits> localed_string;

int main()
{
    localed_string s1 = L"z", s2 = L"å", s3 = L"ä", s4 = L"ö";

    std::cout << (s1 < s2 && s2 < s3 && s3 < s4 ) << "\n"; //Outputs 0
    std::locale::global(std::locale("sv_SE.UTF-8"));
    std::cout << (s1 < s2 && s2 < s3 && s3 < s4 ) << "\n"; //Outputs 1

    return 0;
}
```

Howerver, it doesn't seem to work if you base it on `char` instead of `wchar_t` and I have no idea why...

Comment: The reason char doesn't work is that it's not using unicode (as in ".UTF-8". You are probably using ISO/IEC 8859-1.

Comment: What is `&a+1` supposed to do?

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you need to use the standard **collate** facet. [Check it out](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=nnRog4I-3jwC&pg=PA280&lpg=PA280&dq=ctype+facet+c%2B%2B+sorting+locale+strings&source=bl&ots=KBC14wQUkR&sig=evL4lVbiRNV9hWMXI5y5Z6yEM3I&hl=pt-BR&ei=Ks2bSsqeDNPEmQfbobnXBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false).