# Sort string array with special characters

Tags: c++, special-characters, sorting

I need to sort an array with special swedish characters. When it reaches a character such as Ö, it will place it in the back of the array. How do I compare the characters, according to the [swedish alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_alphabet)?

Comment: Stick two sweedish fish in your mouth, one on each side representing the two characters.  The first one to get chewed to oblivion is obviously the lesser character.

Comment: @Noah: I'm afraid that's going to be too slow for my application. Do you know of a faster algorithm? (Mmmm, Swedish fish.)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [locale-dependent ordering for std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357374/locale-dependent-ordering-for-stdstring) for locale-specific character and string comparison.