# Sorting in alphabetical with å ä ö

Tags: c++, sorting

I have an algoritm sorting words in alphabetical by the letters value, this all works fine until I include `å ä ö` as they return a `int` value ranging from `-103` to `-124`. Becuse of this the order of the words are like this `ä å ö a` for example, when it should be `a å ä ö.` So how do I make it sort it correctly with `å ä ö` last?

Edit: Im not allowed to use fancy functions, that is why this code is so bare boned, also using `using namespace std`

**My code:**

`pali` is a `vector` of type string that I use to store the words

```
void SortPal() {
int antal = pali.size();
string tempO;
bool byte = false;

for (int i = 0; i < antal - 1; i++) { //går igenom alla ord i vectorn
        if (int(pali[i][0]) > int(pali[i + 1][0])) {
            tempO = pali[i];
            pali[i] = pali[i + 1];
            pali[i + 1] = tempO;
            i = -1;
        }
        else if (int(pali[i][0]) == int(pali[i + 1][0])) { //Om första bokstaven är samma kollar den följande
            int minsta = pali[i].size();
            if (minsta > pali[i + 1].size()) {
                minsta = pali[i + 1].size();
            }
            for (int a = 1; a < minsta-1; a++){
                if (int(pali[i][a]) > int(pali[i + 1][a])) { //byter om någon av bokstäverna efter den första är mindre än bokstäverna i andra ordet
                    tempO = pali[i];
                    pali[i] = pali[i + 1];
                    pali[i + 1] = tempO;
                    i = -1;
                    byte = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (byte == false && pali[i].size() > pali[i + 1].size()) { // byter om pali i+1 är mindre än pali i
                tempO = pali[i];
                pali[i] = pali[i + 1];
                pali[i + 1] = tempO;
                i = -1;
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: There are three places in this code alone that you have repeated swapping logic. That's nine lines that can be replaced by three calls to `std::swap`. I also see a reimplementation of `std::min` in there.

Comment: Have you looked at the input given here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4611302/1025391 ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357374/locale-dependent-ordering-for-stdstring

Comment: im not allowed to use some algoritms for this assignment, it should be as raw as possible. otherwise i would just have used sort

Comment: every program must be programmed using some algorithms. Without algorithms how can it run?

Comment: You are going to want a function that compares two letters according to the rules of your language (swedish?). Numerically comparing the  encoding only (half) works in english. As a bonus, such a function can be used as the final argument to std::sort

Comment: Unless your instructor specifically wants you to support these letters in this specific order you mention, in this specific encoding, **don't bother**.

Comment: Sadly he did, i would much rather add something stopping the input of these characters which would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there's no relationship between the alphabetical order of letters in any given language and numerical codes assigned to said letters in any given character set. In order to compare strings according to the alphabetical order of a given language (or more generally the *collation* order of the current *locale*), C has a special function called [`strcoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcoll).

In order to use it, you need to set up your locale accordingly. Unfortunately, locale names are not standard in C. If you are on Windows, the linked example is unlikely to work.

This is what you should be using in real software. It matters little for you assignment since you are not supposed to use fancy library functions. You need to implement a function similar to `strcoll` yourself, and it should only work for your language.

In a language where each character has its own place in the alphabet, this function is simple: write a function that takes a character and returns its place in the alphabet (e.g. for `'a'` return `1`, for `'b'` return 2, ..., for `'å'` return 27, for `'ä'` return 28...) Compare the strings according to numbers returned by this function. This may or may not take into account letter case depending on what exact sort order you want.

If you don't want to write a big switch, you can use the fact that letters that are in ASCII are already ordered as you want, you only need to fix the order of three additional letters. So you can write something like this:

```
int collation_order(int ch) {
  switch (ch) {
     case 'Å':  return 'Z'+1;
     case 'å':  return 'z'+1;
     case 'Ä':  return 'Z'+2;
     case 'ä':  return 'z'+2;
     case 'Ö':  return 'Z'+3;
     case 'ö':  return 'z'+3;
     default :  return ch;
  }
}

int my_strcoll (char* p, char* q)
{
  int pp, qq;
  while (*p && (pp=collation_order(*p)) == (qq = collation_order(*q))) {
    p++; q++;
  }
  return pp - qq;
}
```

Of course this means that non-alphabetic that come after `Z`/`z` in the ASCII table will get sorted incorrectly. If you want to sort those after Ö/ö, you need to extend `collation_order` accordingly. Try doing this without resorting to a `case` for each individual character.

Another way to write `collation_order` is to use character codes (cast to `unsigned char`) as indices in an array of 256 integer elements.

Also please note that old 8-bit encodings are old and should not be used for serious new development. For more information, read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score -1):

Since your options are constrained and you can also constrain your input to a foreseeable universe, I'd suggest you to use a simple parser function to fit non-ASCII characters inside the places you know they should:

```
int parse_letter( int source )
{
    switch( source )
    {
        case 'å':
        case 'ä':    return 'a';
        case 'ö':    return 'o':
        // as many cases as needed...
        default:     return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: I asked my teacher if i just could add code to stop the input of å ä ö and he said i should rather make the sorting function work correctly with them. But wont this just return the value of a and o, in that case å ä ö wont even end up in the list?

Comment: You can use the parser function only during comparisons and store the original data once classified. This way you'll not lose any information.

Comment: The correct order is probably a, b, ..., z, å, ä, ö.

Comment: Why would you consider "å" and "ä" as an "a"?

Comment: Hi @Phil. I know that Germanic languages handle those characters as separate letters but this is not my choice to flatten them as done for Latin languages. You can find multiple references around. E.g:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/115620
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/212630
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order

Nevertheless, the function I suggested is simple and flexible enough to return anything you want. If you are not happy to map your characters removing diacritics, you can simply return something like `'z' + 1`, `'z' + 2`, `'z' + 3`.